# AWS documentation examples: Clarification

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am (still) trying to implement AWS cognito into my App (ionic 2-3). In the various example aws give, they use variables they don't describe/explain/tell me where it come from. Variables as 'AWS' or 'AWSCognito'

[here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/deploy-and-secure-rest-based-mobile-apps-with-aws-mobile-hub/)

`AWS.config.region = this.config.get('region')`

or [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html)

```
AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';
```

Where do they come from (an import ? but which one ?)
How can I define them ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt a few weeks ago, and search about that... I found this article that explains how exactly we can use [AWS Cognito with Node.js](https://medium.com/@kangzeroo/user-management-with-aws-cognito-1-3-initial-setup-a1a692a657b3#.pgxyg8q8o).

**Obs.:** [This](http://blog.backspace.academy/2015/03/using-cognito-with-nodejs-part-2.html) article uses the official modules from `AWS`, if you wanna do the same.

You can set the region using the following method:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var AWS_Region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.region = AWS_Region;
```

See more about [using AWS Cognito with Node.js](https://medium.com/@kangzeroo/user-management-with-aws-cognito-2-3-the-core-functionality-ec15849618a4).